# Don't understand why this SyntaxError occurs

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

Keep getting this error below, Im assuming the quoted code below is causing it:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary (ctypes.util.find_library ('ssl') or 'libeay32 ')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

**New error now:**

```
c:\Python25>python b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "b.py", line 15, in <module>
    ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
NameError: name 'ssl' is not defined
```

**Update:** *Just* added the whole code below so you guys can see, appreciated if someone can take a look below.
    import hashlib
    import ctypes
    import ctypes.util
    import urllib2
    import sys
    import codecs

```
ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')

def check_result (val, func, args):
    if val == 0: raise ValueError
    else: return ctypes.c_void_p (val)

ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name.errcheck = check_result

class KEY:
    def __init__(self):
        NID_secp256k1 = 714
        self.k = ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)
        self.compressed = False
        self.POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED = 2
        self.POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED = 4

    def __del__(self):
        if ssl:
            ssl.EC_KEY_free(self.k)
        self.k = None

    def generate(self, secret=None):
        if secret:
            priv_key = ssl.BN_bin2bn(secret, 32, ssl.BN_new())
            group = ssl.EC_KEY_get0_group(self.k)
            pub_key = ssl.EC_POINT_new(group)
            ctx = ssl.BN_CTX_new()
            ssl.EC_POINT_mul(group, pub_key, priv_key, None, None, ctx)
            ssl.EC_KEY_set_private_key(self.k, priv_key)
            ssl.EC_KEY_set_public_key(self.k, pub_key)
            ssl.EC_POINT_free(pub_key)
            ssl.BN_CTX_free(ctx)
            return self.k
        else:
            return ssl.EC_KEY_generate_key(self.k)

    def set_privkey(self, key):
        self.mb = ctypes.create_string_buffer(key)
        ssl.d2i_ECPrivateKey(ctypes.byref(self.k), ctypes.byref(ctypes.pointer(self.mb)), len(key))

    def set_pubkey(self, key):
        self.mb = ctypes.create_string_buffer(key)
        ssl.o2i_ECPublicKey(ctypes.byref(self.k), ctypes.byref(ctypes.pointer(self.mb)), len(key))

    def get_privkey(self):
        size = ssl.i2d_ECPrivateKey(self.k, 0)
        mb_pri = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
        ssl.i2d_ECPrivateKey(self.k, ctypes.byref(ctypes.pointer(mb_pri)))
        return mb_pri.raw

    def get_pubkey(self):
        size = ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(self.k, 0)
        mb = ctypes.create_string_buffer(size)
        ssl.i2o_ECPublicKey(self.k, ctypes.byref(ctypes.pointer(mb)))
        return mb.raw

    def get_secret(self):
        bn = ssl.EC_KEY_get0_private_key(self.k);
        bytes = (ssl.BN_num_bits(bn) + 7) / 8
        mb = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bytes)
        n = ssl.BN_bn2bin(bn, mb);
        return mb.raw.rjust(32, chr(0))

    def set_compressed(self, compressed):
        self.compressed = compressed
        if compressed:
            form = self.POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED
        else:
            form = self.POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED
        ssl.EC_KEY_set_conv_form(self.k, form)

def dhash(s):
    return hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(s).digest()).digest()

def rhash(s):
    h1 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    h1.update(hashlib.sha256(s).digest())
    return h1.digest()

b58_digits = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def base58_encode(n):
    l = []
    while n > 0:
        n, r = divmod(n, 58)
        l.insert(0,(b58_digits[r]))
    return ''.join(l)

def base58_decode(s):
    n = 0
    for ch in s:
        n *= 58
        digit = b58_digits.index(ch)
        n += digit
    return n

def base58_encode_padded(s):
    res = base58_encode(int('0x' + s.encode('hex'), 16))
    pad = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == chr(0):
            pad += 1
        else:
            break
    return b58_digits[0] * pad + res

def base58_decode_padded(s):
    pad = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == b58_digits[0]:
            pad += 1
        else:
            break
    h = '%x' % base58_decode(s)
    if len(h) % 2:
        h = '0' + h
    res = h.decode('hex')
    return chr(0) * pad + res

def base58_check_encode(s, version=0):
    vs = chr(version) + s
    check = dhash(vs)[:4]
    return base58_encode_padded(vs + check)

def base58_check_decode(s, version=0):
    k = base58_decode_padded(s)
    v0, data, check0 = k[0], k[1:-4], k[-4:]
    check1 = dhash(v0 + data)[:4]
    if check0 != check1:
        raise BaseException('checksum error')
    if version != ord(v0):
        raise BaseException('version mismatch')
    return data

def gen_eckey(passphrase=None, secret=None, pkey=None, compressed=False, rounds=1):
    k = KEY()
    if passphrase:
        secret = passphrase.encode('utf8')
        for i in xrange(rounds):
            secret = hashlib.sha256(secret).digest()
    if pkey:
        secret = base58_check_decode(pkey, 128)
        compressed = len(secret) == 33
        secret = secret[0:32]
    k.generate(secret)
    k.set_compressed(compressed)
    return k

def get_addr(k):
    pubkey = k.get_pubkey()
    secret = k.get_secret()
    hash160 = rhash(pubkey)
    addr = base58_check_encode(hash160)
    payload = secret
    if k.compressed:
        payload = secret + chr(1)
    pkey = base58_check_encode(payload, 128)
    return addr, pkey

def test():
    # random uncompressed
    print get_addr(gen_eckey())
    # random compressed
    print get_addr(gen_eckey(compressed=True))
    # by secret
    print get_addr(gen_eckey(secret=('%064x' % 0xdeadbabe).decode('hex')))
    # by passphrase
    print get_addr(gen_eckey(passphrase='Satoshi Nakamoto'))
    # by private key, uncompressed
    print get_addr(gen_eckey(pkey='5K1HkbYffstTZDuV4riUWMbAMkQh57b8798uoy9pXYUDYeUHe7F'))
    # by private key, compressed
    print get_addr(gen_eckey(pkey='L3ATL5R9Exe1ubuAnHVgNgTKZEUKkDvWYAWkLUCyyvzzxRjtgyFe'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_file = "dictionary.txt"
    found_file = "found_addresses.txt"
    abe_server = "localhost"
    abe_port = "2750"
    abe_chain = "Bitcoin"
    print "Starting search for used brainwallet addresses using dictionary '%s'" % dict_file

    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(dict_file))

    line_count = 0
    found = codecs.open(found_file,'a','utf8')
    dictionary = codecs.open(dict_file,'r','utf8')
    for raw_line in dictionary:
        line_count += 1
        line = raw_line.rstrip()
        a = get_addr(gen_eckey(passphrase=line))
        address = a[0]
        private_address = a[1]
        try:
            url = "http://%s:%s/chain/%s/q/getreceivedbyaddress/%s" % (abe_server, abe_port, abe_chain, address)
            received_bitcoins = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print "Request failed for word '%s' to URL '%s'" % (line, url)
            continue

        if(received_bitcoins != "0"):
            msg = "Found address %s using dictionary word %s which has received %s bitcoins. Private key: %s\n" % (address, line.rstrip(), received_bitcoins, private_address)
            print msg
            found.write(msg)
        if( (line_count % 1000) == 0 ):
            print "Progress: %s of %s words checked so far" % (line_count, num_lines)

    found.close()
    dictionary.close()
```

Comment: That code is *not* raising a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Did you mean to call `ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for replying Bakuriu, i have no idea, im new to python

Comment: Whats line 7 and 8 of your b.py?

Comment: @Ank: You can see that in both the traceback and in the posted code; the `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` line is line 8.

Comment: what happens when you do `import ctypes` on python command line?

Comment: Your traceback and script show different code. Will you please update both your traceback and code sample to what you are currently using/receiving?

Comment: ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32') will not put ssl into scope.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `find_libary` is failing and then it can not load `'libeay32 '` - Possibly because it is missing or the space at the end may not help.

If the code is as posted the syntax error is that you are not assigning anything to ssl.

I would suggest changing:

```
ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')
```

to:

```
libname = ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')
print ('Library found as', libname)
if libname:
   ssl = ctypes.LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(libname)
else:
   sys.exit()
```

Comment: hmm cant see no white space :(

Comment: after the 2 and before the '

Comment: In the traceback see line with `ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary (ctypes.util.find_library ('ssl') or 'libeay32 ')` which is _not_ the same as the `ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')` near the beginning of the code.

Comment: Code does not match trace back.

Comment: @user1261605: the `NameError: name 'ssl' is not defined` is because in the code you're referencing it in the line `ssl.EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name.restype = ctypes.c_void_p` but there's nothing prior to that which defines a variable named `ssl`.

Comment: `ctypes.util.load_library` doesn't exist. Use `ssl = ctypes.CDLL(libname)`.

Comment: `ctypes.LibraryLoader` needs to be instantiated with a `dlltype`. There's already a `ctypes.cdll` instance, defined as `ctypes.LibraryLoader(CDLL)`. Its `LoadLibrary` method simply returns `self._dlltype(name)`. In other words you can just use `ctypes.CDLL(libname)`. The point of the `LibraryLoader` instances (also `windll`, `oledll`, `pydll`) is for use with Windows DLLs. It allows you to use `cdll.msvcrt` or `cdll.libeay32` because Windows will append `.dll` to the name. It caches the resulting `CDLL` instance, which in turn caches the function pointers that get created dynamically.